# VBA Code in Workbook_BeforeClose runs but has no effect

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in an Excel 2010 workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim FileName As String

    FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    If FileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

    If FileName <> "Shipping Manifest SaveAS Update.xlsm" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, WriteResPassword:="abc123", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The code executes if I insert a breakpoint and run it line-by-line, but when I reopen the workbook it does not prompt for the "abc123" password to open not in Read Only mode - it just opens. What am I doing wrong? I made sure macros are enabled.

Comment: Not being rude but it has caught me out before, are you opening the right one to check? if you look in your Documents folder (generally C:\users\[USERNAME]\documents\[FileN\me].xlsm) it may be there, you didnt provide a full path, so it may be placing it in your 'documents' folder by default.

Comment: Good point, but it is saving to the expected location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've suppressed alerts with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. Remove this line, and you'll see what the problem is.

When alerts are disabled, Excel uses the default option. In this case, you would be warned that a file already exists, and Excel wants you to confirm that it's OK to overwrite. The default option to this Yes/No/Cancel is "No", so it would appear that the file is not actually being saved.

The other potential problem is that you may be confusing `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook`.  The `_BeforeClose` event will only run from the workbook that it's in, so there is arguably no reason to do any sort of name check, assuming you always want to save the workbook where this code resides, when you close it.

Instead, try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    With ThisWorkbook
        .WritePassword = "abc123"
        .ReadOnlyRecommended = True
        .Save
    End With
End Sub
```

The above assumption may not hold if the workbook is being closed programmatically, in which case you *may* need a distinction between `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook`, but it's hard to imagine why when closing *this* workbook, you'd want to save a different (active) workbook.

Also, to Gary's comment above (and I've tested this) if you're not providing a full path, the file will be saved to your Documents folder (at least it is for me in Excel 2013).

You may need to do:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, WriteResPassword:="abc123", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True
```

In your code, as:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> "Shipping Manifest SaveAS Update.xlsm" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, WriteResPassword:="abc123", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution partially works. It is applying the ReadOnlyRecommended, but not the WritePassword. I can't use WriteResPasswords, it's not a method of the BeforeClose event.

Comment: OK, then with minimal change make your code do: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, WriteResPassword:="abc123", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True`

Comment: Using FullName worked. This will be run by an application that will open a template and save it under a new name. One of the requirements is that the new file can only be opened for editing by people who know the password; for all others it will open as Read Only. We can't have the template opening as Read Only, hence the name comparison.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the "cancel as Boolean" and it worked perfectly

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose()
Dim FileName As String



FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

If FileName = "False" Then Exit Sub


If FileName <> "Shipping Manifest SaveAS Update.xlsm" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, WriteResPassword:="abc123", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: No it didn't :)  If this code actually works then you've placed an event procedure in a standard module and it won't fire as an event.  You can't remove the `Cancel` argument from the BeforeClose event, it's required, so if you have this code in the Workbook module, you'll get a compile error.

Comment: i will concede that i know far less about this than you have demonstrated.
that being said: mine did run. it did save. and upon reopening did prompt me for the specified password.
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah, if you remove the Cancel As Boolean from the event it errors out.

Comment: yep... jumped the gun a bit.  mine doesn't give any errors (i also removed display alerts false) but it isn't doing a save as